# Interchangeability of nightlights between two data(DMSP OLS) and VIRRS

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I am collecting nighttime lights in African countries between 1992-2021 to utilize it as an economic growth indicator.

So far, I have managed to correct them from two data;

1. 1992-2013 from DMSP OLS Nighttime Lights Time Series Version 4 (band: avg_vis)
2. 2014-2021 from VIIRS Nighttime Day/Night Band Composites Version 1 (band: avg_rad)

However, I came up with the question that the indicator of nightlight evaluation differ over two data. Could you please help me to figure out how to maintain interchangeability between them? (Is there any kind of conversion coefficient?)

My code is [here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/?scriptPath=users%2Fmjk22001%2Ffirst_Test_NightLight%3Atest2).

```
Map.centerObject(table,2);
Map.addLayer(table,{},"Africa");

var countryList = ["Algeria", "Angola", "Benin", "Botswana", "Burkina Faso", "Burundi", "Cameroon", "Cape Verde", "Central African Republic", "Chad", "Comoros", "Republic of the Congo", " CÃ´te d'Ivoire", "Democratic Republic of the Congo", "Djibouti", "Egypt", "Equatorial Guinea", "Eritrea", "Ethiopia", "Gabon", "Gambia", "Ghana", "Guinea", "Guinea-Bissau", "Kenya", "Lesotho", "Liberia", "Libya", "Madagascar", "Malawi", "Mali", "Mauritania", "Mauritius", "Morocco", "Mozambique", "Namibia", "Niger", "Nigeria", "Rwanda", "Sao Tome and Principe", "Senegal", "Seychelles", "Sierra Leone", "Somalia", "South Africa", "South Sudan", "Sudan", "Swaziland", "Togo", "Tunisia", "Uganda", "Tanzania", "Zambia", "Zimbabwe"];
var countries = ee.FeatureCollection('USDOS/LSIB_SIMPLE/2017').filter(ee.Filter.inList("country_na", countryList));

Map.addLayer(countries,{},"countries of interest");

Map.centerObject(countries,2);

// import the nightlight image collection


// set the start and end dates from 1992-2021
var start = ee.Date.fromYMD(2014,1,1);
var end = ee.Date.fromYMD(2014,12,31);

var start_1992 = ee.Date.fromYMD(1992,1,1);
var end_1992 = ee.Date.fromYMD(1992,12,31);

var start_1992 = ee.Date.fromYMD(1992,1,1);
var end_1992 = ee.Date.fromYMD(1992,12,31);

var start_1993 = ee.Date.fromYMD(1993,1,1);
var end_1993 = ee.Date.fromYMD(1993,12,31);

var start_1994 = ee.Date.fromYMD(1994,1,1);
var end_1994 = ee.Date.fromYMD(1994,12,31);

var start_1995 = ee.Date.fromYMD(1995,1,1);
var end_1995 = ee.Date.fromYMD(1995,12,31);

var start_1996 = ee.Date.fromYMD(1996,1,1);
var end_1996 = ee.Date.fromYMD(1996,12,31);

var start_1997 = ee.Date.fromYMD(1997,1,1);
var end_1997 = ee.Date.fromYMD(1997,12,31);

var start_1998 = ee.Date.fromYMD(1998,1,1);
var end_1998 = ee.Date.fromYMD(1998,12,31);

var start_1999 = ee.Date.fromYMD(1999,1,1);
var end_1999 = ee.Date.fromYMD(1999,12,31);

var start_2000 = ee.Date.fromYMD(2000,1,1);
var end_2000 = ee.Date.fromYMD(2000,12,31);

var start_2001 = ee.Date.fromYMD(2001,1,1);
var end_2001 = ee.Date.fromYMD(2001,12,31);

var start_2002 = ee.Date.fromYMD(2002,1,1);
var end_2002 = ee.Date.fromYMD(2002,12,31);

var start_2003 = ee.Date.fromYMD(2003,1,1);
var end_2003 = ee.Date.fromYMD(2003,12,31);

var start_2004 = ee.Date.fromYMD(2004,1,1);
var end_2004 = ee.Date.fromYMD(2004,12,31);

var start_2005 = ee.Date.fromYMD(2005,1,1);
var end_2005 = ee.Date.fromYMD(2005,12,31);

var start_2006 = ee.Date.fromYMD(2006,1,1);
var end_2006 = ee.Date.fromYMD(2006,12,31);

var start_2007 = ee.Date.fromYMD(2007,1,1);
var end_2007 = ee.Date.fromYMD(2007,12,31);

var start_2008 = ee.Date.fromYMD(2008,1,1);
var end_2008 = ee.Date.fromYMD(2008,12,31);

var start_2009 = ee.Date.fromYMD(2009,1,1);
var end_2009 = ee.Date.fromYMD(2009,12,31);

var start_2010 = ee.Date.fromYMD(2010,1,1);
var end_2010 = ee.Date.fromYMD(2010,12,31);

var start_2011 = ee.Date.fromYMD(2011,1,1);
var end_2011 = ee.Date.fromYMD(2011,12,31);

var start_2012 = ee.Date.fromYMD(2012,1,1);
var end_2012 = ee.Date.fromYMD(2012,12,31);

var start_2013 = ee.Date.fromYMD(2013,1,1);
var end_2013 = ee.Date.fromYMD(2013,12,31);

var start_2014 = ee.Date.fromYMD(2014,1,1);
var end_2014 = ee.Date.fromYMD(2014,12,31);

var start_2015 = ee.Date.fromYMD(2015,1,1);
var end_2015 = ee.Date.fromYMD(2015,12,31);

var start_2016 = ee.Date.fromYMD(2016,1,1);
var end_2016 = ee.Date.fromYMD(2016,12,31);

var start_2017 = ee.Date.fromYMD(2017,1,1);
var end_2017 = ee.Date.fromYMD(2017,12,31);

var start_2018 = ee.Date.fromYMD(2018,1,1);
var end_2018 = ee.Date.fromYMD(2018,12,31);

var start_2019 = ee.Date.fromYMD(2019,1,1);
var end_2019 = ee.Date.fromYMD(2019,12,31);

var start_2020 = ee.Date.fromYMD(2020,1,1);
var end_2020 = ee.Date.fromYMD(2020,12,31);

var start_2021 = ee.Date.fromYMD(2021,1,1);
var end_2021 = ee.Date.fromYMD(2021,12,31);

 
// filter for the period of interest
var nightlights2014 = nightlight.filterDate(start,end);
// take the mean note that this operation transforms the image collection into an image
nightlights2014 = ee.Image(nightlights2014.mean());
// select the avg_rad band
nightlights2014 = nightlights2014.select("avg_rad");
// clip for the area of interest
nightlights2014 = nightlights2014.clip(countries);
Map.addLayer(nightlights2014,{min:0,max:10,palette:['000000','700000','808080','FFFF00','ffffff','ffffff','ffffff']},"nightlights 2014");

//create a variable for data export
var data_export_2014 = nightlights2014.reduceRegions({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  collection: countries,
  scale: 450
});

//execution of data export
Export.table.toDrive({
  collection:data_export_2014,
  description: "nightlights2014",
  folder: "nightlights_Africa",
  selectors: (["mean"])
});
```

Comment: Sorry. I shared the wrong link. The right one as follows

https://code.earthengine.google.com/?scriptPath=users%2Fmjk22001%2FNightLight_Africa%3AAfrican%20NightLights%2Fnightlights%20in%20Africa

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it rather than adding comments.

Answer (score 1):

I am working on a similar application and have a partial response and partial solution. Partial because satellite imagery is not my field and, partial solution because it temporarily relieves the issue at hand but loses generality and precision. The quick answer is that both indexes are non-comparable. The data generation process differs across both and this is a good example on why it is important to understand the DGP and the nature of the economic data you use.

DMSP records lights produced by approx 1000-watt lamps from a 25km<sup>2</sup> area. During night, DMSP spatial resolution is of around 5km while using a 2.7km ground sample distance, this implies some distortions. For these reasons, DMSP is old-technology today and it was deprecated and substituted by VIIRS. VIIRS has around 45x higher precision using different technology. Documentation on satellite data will provide you with further information on filters that account for clouds, rasterizing, blurs, etc.

Figure 2.8 [here](https://worldbank.github.io/OpenNightLights/tutorials/mod1_2_introduction_to_nighttime_light_data.html) will give you a great idea on the different resolution the index is constructed with. It makes quite clear that the DGP of the radiance index suffered a structural change after changing satellite technology. The implication to your application is that rural areas are often neglected or not well captured by DMSP, the scale is also different, and, in sum, both indexes are apples and oranges.

You cannot append them into one series without losing rigor.

Then again, and as a... half-correction, you may implement an interaction in your estimator. Generate an indicator that is 1 when using VIIRS data, and 0 when using DMSP. You need to account for the fact that DMSP composites are annual vs monthly. This is the simplest "solution," and you may notice it is problematic: the dummy adjusts the mean across both variables to account for the structural break. From its simplicity, I find it to be more tractable than relying on filters or chain methods.